# how do i set titleBar text from a sub class

Tags: android, android-context, android-titlebar

I have a Main activity that loads two classes into a FrameLayout view..

```
    //Create Intance of Camera
        camPreview = new CamLayer(this.getApplicationContext());

        //Create Instance of OpenGL
        glView = new GLLayer(this);

        //FrameLayOut for holding everything
        FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(this);
        // set as main view
        setContentView(frame);

        // add Camera to view 
        frame.addView(camPreview, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        frame.addView(glView);
```

from the glView i launch my sensor manager, called PhoneOrientation like so:

```
    public GLLayer(Context context) {
    super(context);

    this.context = context;
    this.square = new Square();
    phoneOri=new PhoneOrientation(context); // sensor manager and interpreter

    // settings for translucent glView
    this.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
    this.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    // set render to inline 
    this.setRenderer(this);
    phoneOri.start(context);

}
```

my phoneOrientation class:

```
    public class PhoneOrientation {
private SensorManager sensorMan;
private Sensor sensorAcce;
private Sensor sensorMagn;
private SensorEventListener listener;
private float matrix[]=new float[16];
private Context ctx;

public PhoneOrientation(Context context) {
    ctx = context;
}

public void start(Context context) {
    listener = new SensorEventListener() {
        private float orientation[]=new float[3];
        private float acceleration[]=new float[3];

        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1){}

        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent evt) {
            int type=evt.sensor.getType();

            //Smoothing the sensor data a bit seems like a good idea.
            if (type == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
                orientation[0]=(orientation[0]*1+evt.values[0])*0.5f;
                orientation[1]=(orientation[1]*1+evt.values[1])*0.5f;
                orientation[2]=(orientation[2]*1+evt.values[2])*0.5f;
            } else if (type == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
                acceleration[0]=(acceleration[0]*2+evt.values[0])*0.33334f;
                acceleration[1]=(acceleration[1]*2+evt.values[1])*0.33334f;
                acceleration[2]=(acceleration[2]*2+evt.values[2])*0.33334f;
            }
            if ((type==Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) || (type==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)) {
                float newMat[]=new float[16];
                //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ctx.getApplicationContext(), "accel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                //toast.show();
                SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(newMat, null, acceleration, orientation);
                SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(newMat,
                        SensorManager.AXIS_Y, SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X,
                        newMat);
                matrix=newMat;
            }
        }
    };

    sensorMan = (SensorManager)context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensorAcce = sensorMan.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).get(0);
    sensorMagn = sensorMan.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD).get(0);

    sensorMan.registerListener(listener, sensorAcce, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    sensorMan.registerListener(listener, sensorMagn, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);       
}

public float[] getMatrix() {
    return matrix;
}

public void finish() {
    sensorMan.unregisterListener(listener);
}
```

}

My phoniOrientationClass is essentially my sensor manager and from there i would like to spit back some of the sensor data to the title bar of my application, ie.

```
    context.setTitle("x: "+ xData); // or something?
```

It doesn't seem like i can make this call from there though?  I am new to java and I see  a lot of people inline their classes in tutorials/examples.  I personally don't like to do that much as i believe it makes messy code.  But i thought since i was passing my application context from my main activity to my glView and then again to my sensor manager that i would be able to make this call?  can someone explain to me how i can?

el

Comment: no, but thats because i am not calling it yet.. i am asking how to reference the title bar from the phoneOrientation class (ie. sensorManager)  i thought i could say context.setTitle("hello");  but setTitle gets a big red line under it in eclipse when i write that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "big red line" under the method means: "The method setTitle(String) is undefined for the type Context". Fortunately this can be fixed very quickly by casting context to Activity.

```
Activity activity = (Activity) context;
activity.setTitle("x: "+ xData);
```

Comment: thanks.. i knew it meant that it was not available.. but thats exactly what i was looking for!